# Password Reset User Flow Account Doesn't Exist Error

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, reset-password

I have a User Flow for Password Reset set up with Email Verification. When I verify an email account that doesn't exist in our AD group, there's an error

[image: password reset page in question]

There appears the error "An Account Could Not Be Found for this user ID". 
Hitting 'Continue' causes a "Please wait while we process your information" message.

Hitting continue again a few times seems to take me to an error url like: B2C_1_ResetPassword/api/SelfAsserted/error?code=UX012   ... max retries reached

I have a Hacky Fix of sorts that binds Clicking on the Continue when the Error message is present to disabling the Continue button.

```
    <script>
    $("#continue").click(function (){
        var claimVerification = $('#claimVerificationServerError:contains("account could not be found for the provided user")');
        if(claimVerification.length > 0){
            $("#continue").prop("disabled", true);
        }
    });
    </script>
```

I have to "Enable JavaScript enforcing page layout (preview)" option turned on for this to sort of work though.

Is there a more correct solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

As I tested with our default experiences as well as the current available templates, it doesn't seem like "Please wait while we process your information" will ever display persistently. Can you check if your css is not adding additional properties to the element used for displaying such message?

For the second scenario, it is for now by design to redirect to your client where you can setup certain logic to handle the error code "AADB2C90157" we return from the url.